# Getting an array of files into a java class

Tags: java, arrays, file, import

I'm writing a program that takes in two types of files and outputs a combination of their contents.  The details of this part are unimportant.  All I need to know is how to add the files of two directories into two separate arrays so that I can iterate through all of them and perform my work on them more simply than loading each file individually. The files have the same names but different extensions.  So by loading the files into arrays, since they are in the same order, I will be able to iterate through them and get my desired information.  Any suggestions?

edit: here is the code

```
import java.io.File;


public class FileImporter 
{
    File[] metricsFiles;
    File[] logFiles;

    public FileImporter()
    {
        metricsFiles = new File(System.getProperty("/Users/aarongrove/Desktop/Code Generator data/metrics")).listFiles();
    }
    public void printFiles()
    {
        for (int i=0;i < metricsFiles.length;i++) 
        {
            System.out.println(metricsFiles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just load them into an array and iterate..? I don't see the problem.

Comment: You can edit your question, just add the code there.

Answer (score 1):

Use [File.list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29), see e.g. these:

- http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/GetFiles.html
- http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.io/list-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-particular-dire.html

Comment: Note that `File.listFiles()` could save time if you need to use the file later, as it returns `File` objects instead of just `Strings`

Comment: Where exactly are you referring to? That was my intention, as I do need to use the files. Is my `.listFiles()` in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DirectoryWalker](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/DirectoryWalker.html) from Apache commons, it allows you to walk through a directory hierarchy.